# Spring/JPA @OneToMany relationship returns a list of size 0, when it should return more. Why?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am using spring/jpa for a project, and I have an entity which has an @OneToMany annotation on a List.The other entity has an @ManyToOne annotation. Although when I retrieve the parent entity by its id, the size of the returned List (child entity) is always 0

Text version of test

```
@Test
public void createReccomendation() throws ServiceException, FileNotFoundException, UserDoesNotExistException, UserNameIsNotUniqueException, IllegalUserNameException {
    String uid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    Employee employee = employeeService.createEmployee("hi", uid+"@me.com", uid, "secret password", 23.234, 23.23, "image", "23dAD", "seattle", "usa");

    List<String> images = new ArrayList<>();

    String image1 = "image1/url";
    String image2 = "image2/url";
    String image3 = "image3/url";

    images.add(image1);
    images.add(image2);
    images.add(image3);

    Employee e = employeeService.getEmployeeById(employee.getId());
    Recommendation rec = recommendationService.createRecommendation(e.getId(),  "title", "Description", 23.23, 23.23, "persikogatan", "stockholm", "Sweden", images);

    Recommendation rec2 = recommendationService.getRecommendationById(rec.getId());

    Assert.assertEquals(rec.getTitle(), "title");
    Assert.assertEquals(rec.getRecommendationimages().get(0).getPath(), image1);
    Assert.assertEquals(3, rec2.getRecommendationimages().size());
}
```

This parent entity

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "recommendation")
    public class Recommendation extends BusinessEntity {

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "employeeid")
        private Employee employee;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recommendation", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        List<RecommendationImage> recommendationimages;

        public Recommendation() {}

        public Recommendation(Employee employee, String title, String description, double targetLat, double targetLong,
                              String street, String city, String country,  List<RecommendationImage> images
                              ) {
            this.employee = employee;
            this.title = title;
            this.description = description;
            this.targetLat = targetLat;
            this.targetLong = targetLong;
            this.street = street;
            this.city = city;
            this.country = country;
            this.active = true;
            this.recommendationimages = images;
        }
```

And this child entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "recommendationimage")
public class RecommendationImage extends ImageEntity{

    @ManyToOne
    private Recommendation recommendation;
```

Super class of child entity

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class ImageEntity extends BaseEntity{

    @Column(name="path", length=700)
    String path;

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

}
```

RecommendationService class

```
 @Service
    public class RecommendationService{

        private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(DealService.class);


        @Autowired
        RecommendationRepository recommendationRepository;

    public Recommendation getRecommendationById(Long id){
            return recommendationRepository.findOne(id);
        }


    }

public List<RecommendationImage> translateToRecommendationImages(List<String> rawImages) throws ServiceException {
    try{
        List<RecommendationImage> recommendationImages = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String image: rawImages){
            RecommendationImage newImage = new RecommendationImage(image);
            recommendationImages.add(newImage);
        }
        return recommendationImages;
    }catch(Exception e){
        log.warn("** SERVICE EXCEPTION ** FOR METHOD: translateRecommendationImages()");
        throw new ServiceException("Could not translate raw images to RecommendationImage", e);
    }
}

    public Recommendation createRecommendation(Long employeeId, String title, String description, double targetLat,
                                               double targetLong, String street, String city, String country,
                                               List<String> rawImages) throws ServiceException {

        log.info("createRecommendation(): employeeId: "+employeeId+" recommendationTitle: "+title);
        Employee employee=null;
        Recommendation rec=null;
        String imagepath=null;
        try {
            List<RecommendationImage> images = translateToRecommendationImages(rawImages);
            employee = employeeRepository.getEmployeeByid(employeeId);
            rec = new Recommendation(employee, title, description, targetLat, targetLong, street, city, country, images);
//            Recommendation rec2 = CheckProximity.getRecommendationProximity(rec, employee);
            return recommendationRepository.save(rec);
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.warn("** SERVICE EXCEPTION ** FOR METHOD: createRecommendation(): employeeId: "+employeeId);
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ServiceException("Could not create recommendation at this time: "+rec.toString(), e);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: It would make things a bit easier if also test case was text, not image. Are those _employee-_ & _recommendationService_ something Spring generated or your made (sry, asking cause not so familiar with Spring stufff )?

Comment: @Dan, could you please replace a screenshot with one which has all code visible?

Comment: @Eugene I have replaced the image with text version of the test.

Comment: @pirho I have made things easier to read by replacing image with text, and showing the recommendationService. It simply calls a findOne method whose implementation is provided by JPA

Comment: Can we see BusinessEntity class, and also Employee entity and its superclass if any. It might have something to do with ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowhere in your supplied code to you actually populate the list of `RecommendationImage`s. So I'm going to guess.

When dealing with bidirectional relationships, in order for them to be persisted, the side of the relationship without the mappedBy needs to be updated. I'm guessing that you add `RecommendationImage`s to your `Recommendation`, without setting the `Recommendation` of your `RecommendationImage`s.

Typically, you would need a method like this:

```
public class Recommendation {
    //...
    private List<RecommendationImage> images = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addRecommendationImage(final RecommendationImage newImage) {
         recommendationImages.add(newImage);
         newImage.setRecommendation(this);
    }
}
```

Update: With the new code supplied it seems my guess was correct. Make the changes above, and then change the for-loop in `translateToRecommendationImages` to this:

```
public List<RecommendationImage> translateToRecommendationImages(Recommendation recommendation, List<String> rawImages) throws ServiceException {
    //try and whatnot
    for(String image: rawImages){
        recommendation.addRecommendationImage(new RecommendationImage(image));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks I have addd the code that was missing. What I do is I set the List<RecommendationImage> in the constructor of the recommendations. So it should be set that way.

Comment: Wait, it looks like you actually set the Recommendation (parent) to the RecommendationImage (child) object, I am not doing that. I set the List<RecommendationImage> to the Recommendation, but your example suggests I should do the opposite, I will give that a try.

Comment: The "parent" is actually the side without the "mappedBy"-attribute. It's what is populated on that side that decides what is stored. The whole parent-child thing becomes a bit strange though, seeing as it's only the OneToMany annotation that supports mappedBy.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. I did not realize that I had to actually set the employee in each RecommendationImage as well as set the List<RecommendationImage> to the employee. I thought the cascading would take care of the former. But that solved it for me. Thanks!